# Add Jupyter Notetbook to application menu

Tags: 20.04, unity, appmenu

I created a desktop icon for jupyter notebook by creating jupyter.dekstop in my home/arthur/desktop folder and can start jupyter-notebook by double clicking it.

```
Desktop Entry
Type=Application
Name=Jupyter
GenericName=Jupyter Notebook
Icon=/home/arthur/.local/share/icons/jupyter.png
Exec=/home/arthur/miniconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook
Categories=Development;
Terminal=False
StartupNotify=True
```

I then copied jupyter.dekstop to /usr/share/applications/jupyter.desktop but I can't see  it in application menue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may have forgotten to mark it at executable.

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/share/applications/jupyter.desktop
```

If it still does not show up, restart your computer.

Comment: Still not showing up

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question so I'm answering in case anybody else sees this. It looks like the format of the file is incorrect. The first line should be `[Desktop Entry]`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I downloaded my favorite icon from Google and save it with the new name of `Jupyter-lab.png`
after that, I moved the png file to  `~/.local/share/icons` with this code on the terminal:

```
sudo mv jupyter-lab.png ~/.local/share/icons
```

I create a text on my desktop in the terminal with this code:
`touch jupyter-lab.desktop`
then I copied these lines to this file. *(Change [MYUSERNAME] with your user)*

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Jupyter Lab
Comment=Run Jupyter Lab
Exec=/home/[MYUSERNAME]/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-lab
Icon=/home/[MYUSERNAME]/.local/share/icons/Jupyter-lab.png
Type=Application
Categories=Development;Education
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=jupyter-lab
Actions=open-browser
```

Then I copied this file to `~/.local/share/applications` by this code on terminal:

```
mv jupyter-lab.desktop  ~/.local/share/applications
```